# WebView finishes launching Mac OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, webview

I want to know if its possible to launch the javascript function

```
[WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Next()"];
```

after the WebView has finished loading in a Mac OS X app, not iOS. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [WebFrameLoadDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003828). Especially `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` should be interesting for you.

Comment: I had looked into it before. What is the frame though. I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: - (void)webView:(WebView *)sundaypsalmody didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    
   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Next()";
    
    
}

Comment: WebFrames are in fact HTML framesets or iframes. But it's arbitrary here, since the delegate method is for sure being called for the frame you need. Most of the time it is [yourWebView mainFrame]. Have you declared in the interface that your class is a <WebFrameLoadDelegate>?

Comment: Make sure to remember [theWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:delegate]; too.

Comment: A note of caution that this method is called when all resources have been loaded. That doesn't necessarily mean the DOM has been fully built