# WebView did finish launching does not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, launch

what is wrong with this method?

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
[activityIndicator stopAnimation:self];
}
```

I want to stop the Circular Progress Indicator (`activityIndicator`). But there is something wrong with `- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame`. I am coding for mac osx and not for iOS. I heard something from Delegates, what does that mean?

Comment: What is the problem? Is the method not getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Check to be sure that your UIWebView has set its delegate.  Setting a delegate is basically telling the program who you want to handle events (like taps, gestures, or, in this case, the loading of a webView).  Thus when an event is fired, it will inform the delegate and the delegate can process it.  Maybe if you post more of your code it would help, but I would check your declaration of the UIWebView in question.  Be sure that after you allocate it and initialize it, you set its delegate to self (assuming that this method is in the same class), like so:

```
UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[myWebView setDelegate:self];
```

If you have not set the delegate, it is firing off events and no one is receiving them to process them.  The method you are using is waiting for the specific event sent by any webView.  When it is sent an event message it passes, as a parameter, the webView that triggered.  In any case, put in a log statement to be sure you are entering the method.  That will tell you if it is receiving the event messages.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSLog(@"Did finish loading..."); 
    [activityIndicator stopAnimation:self];
}
```

NOTE: This is as per iOS experience, but should work for Mac OS as well.  Let me know what your log result is, if the method is getting called or not.

Comment: For Mac OS X, it's called `WebView`, (not `UIWebView`), and the delegate in question is the frame load delegate, so `[myWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self]`. That's the main difference here.

Comment: As I've recently found, webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: on OS X is notorious for being called early, even when ensuring the frame parameter is the main frame: before the document bounds are correct, some say before the DOM is complete built <http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904828/592739>. Instead observe WebView's progress notifications WebViewProgressStartedNotification WebViewProgressEstimateChangedNotification and WebViewProgressFinishedNotification.